# Passing a BindableObject to the views

Tags: ios, swiftui, swift5

From the Apple's sessions and Tutorial we have two options to pass BindableObject to the views.

1. Use declare `BindableObject` as a Source of truth in the top view in the hierarchy with `@ObjectBinding` wrapper and pass it to other views with `@Binding` declared.
2. Use declare `BindableObject` as a Source of truth in the top view in the hierarchy with `@EnviromentObject` wrapper, init top view with `.enviroment(BindableObject)` modifier and pass it to other views or with `@Binding` declared, or using `@EnviromentObject`(in this case `BindableObject` will be assigned automatically by SwiftUI and we do not need to pass it on init).

From [Handling User Input tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/handling-user-input) if we have `BindableObject` with list of items in and we want to change one of the items on other view(or RowView or even separate screen) we need to:

1. Pass the `BindableObject` to the deeper view using any of the ways above.

   2. Pass the selected item to this view.
   3. Bind the property of the item with `BindingView` by finding the item in `BindableObject` list.

Some code to make the question clear:

Message model and `BindableObject`

```
struct Message: Identifiable {
    var id: String
    var toggle: Bool = true
}

class MessageStore: BindableObject {

  let didChange = PassthroughSubject<MessageStore, Never>()

  var messagesList: [Message] = testData {
    didSet {
      didChange.send(self)
    }
  }
}
```

MessageView that represents a list of items
struct MessagesView

```
 : View {

    @EnvironmentObject var messageStore: MessageStore

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(messageStore.messagesList) { message in
                NavigationButton(destination: Text(message.id)) {
                    MessageRow(message: message)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Messages"))
        }
    }
}
```

MessageRow that has a Toggle to update the state of particular item in out `BindableObject`

```
struct MessageRow: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var tags: MessageStore
    var message: Message

    var messageIndex: Int {
        tags.messagesList.firstIndex { $0.id == message.id }!
    }


    var body: some View {
       Toggle(isOn: self.$tags.messagesList[self.messageIndex].toggle) {
           Text("Test toogle")
       }
    }

}
```

This approach is shown in the tutorial I mentioned above.

**Question:**
I wanted to pass Message separately as a `@Binding` to work with it in the child view directly, but I wasn't able to implement this.
I became a bit confused. Is it proper way to pass to any view(that should handle bindings) both the `BindableObject` and selected item to bind later the item from `BindableObject` using index? Is there any other way that will allow to pass not a full `BindableObject` but a part of it and bind this part(it should be Source of truth), in our case this part is `Message`?

Comment: Thanks for posting this.  I just encountered the same issue and had your exact same bewildering question.  Apple's own tutorial seems to endorse a kludge that, frankly, I think they should be embarrassed about.  Their new flagship UI system seems to only suit simplistic UIs; it's an amusing limitation to be unable to directly pass a bound sub-object, thus force either an exhaustive search for it or passing an index to it.  Steve Jobs spins in his grave.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overcomplicating it. It seems that all you need is a toggle value in your message. Try this:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List(messageStore.messagesList) { message in
            NavigationButton(destination: Text(message.id)) {
                MessageRow(isTogged: $message.toggle)
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Messages"))
    }
}

struct MessageRow: View {

    @Binding var isToggled: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Toggle(isOn: self.isToggled) {
            Text("Test toogle")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't do so.  MessageRow(isTogged: $message.toggle) will propose you to remove $, because local message is not a Bindable

Comment: Additional imagine more real situation of Message contains some String fields and toggle, and all of them can be edited in the child view. I think in this case we cannot create `@Binding` for each, but we also cannot use `@Binding` var message: Message

Comment: Hmm, I looked over the tutorial you mentioned. They made BindableObject class to monitor changes to the model. If you add that capability and omit $ sign, changes you make in child views will be automatically added and sync with your model.

Comment: Looks you misunderstand my question in their tutorial have a full BindableObject and subobject that is contained in the array in the BindableObject. To make it working with child views they are passing to the child view the subobject and using it to find the index of this subobject in the BindableObject. It looks very strange, so I am asking about another ways to implement such complex data model structure. The idea is to find good architecture way, not just a workaround like in their example